# Why is the question about topic modelling book for math student off-topic?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

The question [Is there any book about topic modelling in machine learning for math student?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4711203/157643) is closed with the reason that it's not about mathematics.

Reading [What topics can I ask about here? - Help Center - Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), I fail to know why. The closest reason I see may be:

> Questions seeking personal advice for choosing a course, academic program, career path, etc. Such questions should be directed to those employed by the institution in question, or other qualified individuals who know your specific circumstances.

But it's about books, not courses.

Moreover, I don't see how this question is any different to [What is a good book for math students to learn machine learning in depth?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1857677/157643), which has 4 answers and stays opened for 6 years.

Can you help me explain why?

Comment: I am unsure if this question *is* about maths, in the sense that the ideal person to answer your question is a mathematician who has made the leap into machine learning; you are more likely to find such people on a machine learning site than on a mathematics site. After looking briefly at the [tag:machine-learning] tag, there does not seem to be a very active ML community here.

Comment: You're comparing a question from three days ago to a question from seven years ago. Cultural norms change, what is accepted or not accepted changes with it.

Comment: @AsafKaragila then why doesn't the help page reflect this change?

Comment: @Ooker The word "etc." is suitably vague, and gives space for cultural norms to shift without needing to be edited.

Comment: Sister site [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour) takes on machine learning as a central topic.  I'm not a frequent participant there, but you might find their [self-study tagged Questions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-study?tab=Active) of interest.  Your Question on Math.SE has been reopened.

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly off-topic, but some scam PR were trying to promote their books using this strategy previously:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19676403/running-python-in-powershell
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11813435/im-trying-to-use-python-in-powershell

Probably it's overload for Stack to investigate every case for hidden promotion, and more clean approach is to ban the very concept of such broad questions which clearly lead to advertisements in answers.

"Is there any book about topic modelling in machine learning for math student?" rephrased to
"What is roadmap for topic modelling in machine learning for math student?"
sounds much better to me.